# Is this circuit a series or parallel combination?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]I’ve been confused on this aspect of my textbook. To me it appears that the answer is that it is both a series and parallel combination of elements, but I’m not sure if that is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's both. The voltages indicate parallel but the currents indicate series. Sort of pointless either way since it is only ever true for two components and with just two components you never need to use the concept of series or parallel.